# Cannot access a server from a specific network but can access it from everywhere else

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, routing, internet-connection

At my office, I have forwarded some ports to my machine so I can host several test services and allow RDP access in case I have to connect from outside.

It works perfectly when I connect from everywhere except for my home network. I cannot access from any device connected to my house network.

I can ping the IP and domains that point to my office network and it would respond just fine losing no packets at all.

Any connection however will try to connect forever. When I browse the web page I have hosted, it remains loading forever, sometimes it manages to load some inputs with no styles but it will never load properly.

When trying to access RDP it asks for username and password and tries to connect for a long while and then throws a connection error, sometimes it establishes the connection and goes full screen but throws an error seconds later.

I have no idea of how to find the problem and fix it. What could it be?

Thank you so much!

PS. When I connect to a hamachi network I get a relayed tunnel to that machine.

Comment: We need much more information about your home network setup in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remote from one device to another, they are either required to be in the same network segment for direct access or connecting via VPN/RD gateway(specific role installe for remoting externally).
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-outside-access

Kindly test if the device in your home network could communicate with the target one with telnet command.

**Using Telnet to Test Port 3389 Functionality**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/187628/using-telnet-to-test-port-3389-functionality

Meanwhile, kindly compare the port usage between working and non-working device and ensure the specific ports were not occupied.